# Value of a Moebius sum

Tags: number-theory, finite-fields, mobius-inversion

Let $q$ be a power of a prime, let $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Is the value of the following sum known?

$$
\sum_{d \mid q^n-1} \mu\left( \dfrac{q^n-1}{d}  \right) q^{ord_d(q)},
$$
where $ord_d(q)$ denotes the multiplicative order of $q$ modulo $d$? Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure about $q$ power of prime instead of $q^n$, and about $q^{ord_d(q)}$ instead of $q^{ord_q(d)}$?

Comment: Yes I'm sure of it

Comment: Strange function ... it's 0 the large majority of the time, but there are a few nonzero values. For example, when $q$ is prime and $n=6$, the following are the smallest nonzero values: $q=2$ yields $-60$, $q=13$ yields $-4824456$, $q=37$ yields $-2565674424$, $q=73$ yields $151333832016$, $q=109$ yields $1677098804040$, $q=193$ yields $51682533323136$, $q=433$ yields $6590636705441376$, $q=769$ yields $206803572973831680$, and $q=1153$ yields $-2349502132190628096$.

Comment: It's a bit similar to the sum in the formula for the number of irreducible polynomials of fixed degree in finite fields. See here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IrreduciblePolynomial.html

Since this one given here is a bit more complicated, and the one on irreducibles is not given in terms of elementary functions, probably this will be the same for the sum here...

Comment: Greg Martin, this is very nice.